# Open Windows Folder with a Local HTML Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a local "website" for myself where I have a collection of links that lead to specific items on my PC. Right now, when I click on a link the folder opens, but it does so within the browser.

Is it possible for the links to open a Windows explorer window, and not as a site in a browser?

So far, this site should only work in Windows, not Mac, but it wouldn't be wrong if it works in both.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so anything like that is available which make *OS* file manager to **popout** of web browser

yet you can try [elfinder](http://elfinder.org/)

Comment: yes i did try to remove window. - it works the same. What its about linking to a .bat file? would this work? i mean linking to a .bat file and this .bat fils says to open a specific file?

Comment: so my friend what will be the use of developing a web app if you have to program for particular OS .bat is only for MS-Windows

Comment: if you have to open a file out of browser you can do that with @Andy answer, but open folder out of browser, don't think...

Comment: its not a web app its just an homescreen for my personal pc, so its okay thats .bat only for windows. yeah but open folder out of browser is exactly what i need :D

Comment: you have written "im building an local "website" "